# I wan to send exception message from one quarkus service and another quarkus service. How do I do that?

Tags: exception, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have two services, If any exception is thrown is one service I should be able to receive that exception is other service which is making the call to that service. In short I want to communicate the exception body from one service to another.

Currently the exception response is :
Received: 'Server response is: 500' when invoking: Rest Client method: 'XXX' regardless of whatever the exception message is thrown.

I want the exception message message to be communicated to the calling services.

Solution but not conventional : The Error message I am currently sending throw headers, The exception body is not picked.

Comment: I suppose you can use this approach - https://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/resteasy-exceptionmapper-example/

Answer (score 0):

From your service1 you send Response with any http status you want. At your service2 to while writing client you need to catch `WebApplicationException` to know what status returned by service1 client.

**[Optional]**
You can use `org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.ext.ResponseExceptionMapper` to map http response status to your custom exceptions at your service2